# aesthetics error - not recognizing individual years in date column

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I'm trying to plot multiple years of monthly data in one plot
using this code:

```
TmpData<-read.csv('BeaverDay.csv', header=TRUE)
TmpData$Date <- as.Date(with(TmpData, paste(Year, Month, Day, sep="-" )),"%Y-%m-%d")
dat<-data.frame(Var=TmpData$CaMgDTE , date=TmpData$Date)

ggplot(dat, aes(`year<-`(date, 2011), Var, col = factor(year))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "", col = "year")
```

It works beautifully (sometimes) for one file,

[image]

but not for any other file that is formatted the same way. I cannot figure out what is different between the files or runs.

I keep getting this error:

```
aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data(xxx)
```

and this error:

```
> Error in `geom_line()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `unique.default()`:
! unique() applies only to vectors
```

For one file, it just gives a warning about removing the NAs, but still creates the figure. So I don't think NAs are the problem.

Here is a snippet of the data that works

> data.frame(head(TmpData))
> Day Month Year DateCode JulianD  CaNa AgTUg Al_Diss_Mg Al_T_Mg AsExMg
> 1  17    11 1987    32098     322 16.12    NA         NA      NA     NA
> 2   1    12 1987    32112     336 16.12    NA         NA      NA     NA
> 3  15    12 1987    32126     350 15.05    NA         NA      NA     NA
> 4  29    12 1987    32140     364 16.28    NA         NA      NA     NA
> 5  12     1 1988    32154      12 15.21    NA         NA      NA     NA
> 6  26     1 1988    32168      26 14.68    NA         NA      NA     NA

Here is a snippet of the data that doesn't

> data.frame(head(TmpData))
> Day Month Year DateCode JulianD AgTUg Al_Diss_Mg Al_T_Mg AsExMg AsTMg
> 1   5     6 1981    29742     157    NA         NA      NA     NA    NA
> 2  12    10 1981    29871     286    NA         NA      NA     NA    NA
> 3  18     2 1982    30000      49    NA         NA      NA     NA    NA
> 4  21     6 1982    30123     173    NA         NA      NA     NA    NA
> 5  25     6 1982    30127     177    NA         NA      NA     NA    NA
> 6   2     7 1982    30134     184    NA         NA      NA     NA    NA

(note the variable I am plotting is not shown as the files contain >100 columns)

I've tried changing the plotting year (date, 1988)

I've tried removing NA's but, as stated above NAs are not a problem for one of the files

I've checked the class of the Date column and it is a "Date"

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of `dput(head(2nd_dataframe, n = 20))`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Just include the data directly using e.g. dput(head(NAME_OF_DATA)) or data.frame(...)).

Comment: I find it difficult to see how an aesthetic of `x=\`year<-\`(date, 2000)` could produce an x-axis with 2011 in the year. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your date is likely not actually date. Try to `str(2nd_dataframe)` to see the format and try to use `as.Date()` to change it to class date.

Comment: Sorry, I hope this is better.

Comment: to give example of the data try to use the `dput` function it will give us a piece of code that we can run to get your data